# Missing whitespace between position/job and "and"

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

If we have multiple positions / jobs at the same time set on http://careers.stackoverflow.com/, a whitespace between and/und and the company name is missing.

See the screenshot of my profile.

[image]

Comment: @polyeo well, the links on StackOverflow Careers say that we should post bugreports here on meta. The emaill address linked there is "for paying customers", so is this now forwarded to the internal team or should I send it as email again even if the email address is just for paying customers? How can a bugreport be offtopic anyway? The question fits the bug tag. "Feedback website" https://careers.stackoverflow.com/support

Comment: Those links are wrong for a while. Careers moved to be integral part of Stack Overflow, same way like Questions and Answers on the site, and renamed to Jobs while moving there. Soon (might be days, or weeks) the domain http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ will cease to exist, and redirect to http://stackoverflow.com/jobs.

Comment: After I wrote them via email too and described the bug to them and pointed to this thread here, they fixed it now as it seems.

Comment: Yes, SE employee [Juice](http://stackoverflow.com/users/242131/juice) migrated the question over to MSO.

Comment: Stack Overflow Careers is now /Jobs to candidates on SO. Meta SO with the Jobs tag is where feedback should go.